# How to create a static mock rest server with Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to create easily and very quickly a mock rest server. So I decided to try Apache web server. In Apache, each requested URL must be linked to a file in the corresponding folder:

```
http://host:port/folder1/folder2  ->  /var/tmp/folder1/folder2/file.data
```

I managed to create an alias to bind an URL with a specified file, but
how to create a generic rule to avoid creating one for each URL, and then process POST request? Is it possible to rewrite a POST request into a GET?

Comment: No, it is not possible to internally rewrite a post request into a get request. You can redirect, but the second request would be done without the post data. Why do you not move everything from /var/tmp/ to your www-folder?

Comment: I don't care loosing post data ... so redirect could be a good solution, thanks.